# How to get Cell address in google script on change event

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I want to run a function when I change a specific cell in my google sheets. onEdit(e) function runs whenever I change any cell in my sheet but I want to run a function when I change a specific cell e.g. ws.getRange("b1").
Is there any method like e.range.getAddress in google sheets onEdit event?

Answer (score 1):

#### Using the event object of an onEdit trigger

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));//allows you to view the event object
  if(sh.getName() == "Your sheet name" && e.range.columnStart == "your column number" && e.range.rowStart == "Your row number" && e.value == " Your value") {
    //your operation.  
  }
}
```

If you wish to see the event object of an onChange event then write the function:

```
function onMyChange(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

Create an onEdit trigger for "onMyChange" and make a change.  The got to executions and view the event object.  There will be items in the event object that are not documented.  I use them all of the time and I've never had problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more details about events [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). They provided the following example, it's comparable to your use-case:

```
function onEdit(e){
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  var range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}
```

Comment: As noted by @Felix G and also look at [Range.getA1Notation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getA1Notation()).  In your case it would be `e.range.getA1Notation()`.

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> Is there any method like e.range.getAddress in google sheets onEdit event?

Yes, there is: [Range.getA1Notation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#geta1notation)

```
function onEdit(e){
   const address = e.range.getA1Notation();
   console.log(address);
}
```